# vector.erase error, cannot delete incomplete type

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, actor, incomplete-type

Okay so I'm trying to create an Actor-Behaviour system, and I'm having some trouble with incomplete types, basically, when I try to kill an Actor, it tells me that class Actor is an incomplete type.

So my structure goes as follows:

```
Planet-> Vector of all Actors
Actor-> Vector of all Behaviors
Behaviour-> Game Logic
```

First, we have the Behaviour class, that has a reference to its actor(the actor that added it to its collection), a string holding its type, and functions used for game logic: init(called on start), and tick(called every frame):

```
class Actor;

class Behaviour
{
  protected:
    Actor* actor;
  public:
    string type;
    Behaviour();
    ~Behaviour();
    virtual void Init(); // virtual because every component needs to override them
    virtual void Tick();
}
```

then we have the Actor class, which contains a vector of unique pointers to all of its behaviors, a pointer to its Planet, a unique id, a name, and game logic functions, used to loop through all the behaviors and do game logic!

```
// Actor.h
class Planet;

class Actor
{
  private:
    unsigned id;
    string name;
    vector< unique_ptr< Behaviour > > allBehaviours;
  protected:
    Planet* planet;
  public:
    Actor();
    ~Actor();
    void Init(); // Go through all the behaviors and call their Inits and Ticks
    void Tick();

    template <typename T, typename ...Args>
    void AddBehaviour(Args && ...args); // Creates and adds a new Behaviour of type T to the allBehaviours vector

    template <typename T>
    T& GetBehaviour(std::string type); // Loops through all the Behaviours, and returns the Behaviour whose type is the same as type

// Actor.cpp

#include "Planet.h"
#include "Behaviour.h"
#include "Actor.h"

// Implement Functions
```

That was Actor.h, Actor.cpp implements those functions and includes Planet.h then Behaviour.h then Actor.h!

Now the Planet class contains a vector of unique pointers to all of its Actors, a name, and a unique id generator for its Actors:

```
// Planet.h

class Actor;

class Planet
{
    private:
      unsigned idCounter = 0;
      string name;
      vector< unique_ptr< Actor > > allActors;
    public:
      unsigned GetNewID();
      void Init();
      void Tick(); // Used to loop through all the Actors

      void AddActor(Actor* newActor); // adds a new Actor to the list of all Actors
      void KillActor(int id); // loops through all the Actors and when it finds an Actor whose unique id is matching the id variable it erases it from the allActors vector

}

// Planet.cpp

#include "Public.h"
#include "Actor.h"
#include "Planet.h"

    Planet::KillActor(int id){
        unsigned i = 0;
        for (auto& a : allActors) {
            if (a->GetID() == id)
                allActors.erase(allActors.begin() + i);
            i++;
        }
    }

    // Other Functions
```

I also have a Public.h file that includes stuff like iostream, memory, vector, etc! But does not include files I have created!

And there is a class called Win that has a collection of unique_ptr < Planet >
and there is a public variable called win that is in Public.h ( included everywhere ), each time a Planet is constructed it is pushed to that collection and the Win class has a pointer to the last constructed Planet, so each time an Actor is constructed, this line gets called:

```
{
 // other stuff
 win.GetCurrentPlanet()->AddActor(this); 
}
```

I have tested this structure and it works successfully, I can have multiple Planets and jump from one to another, pointers to Actors work without problems, pointers to Behaviours also work without problems!

Now the problem lies when I call the KillActor function, it loops through all the Actors correctly, it finds the Actor I want to kill then when I call erase upon that Actor it sends me to the file memory, and tells me my program has triggered a breakpoint:

```
void operator()(_Ty *_Ptr) const _NOEXCEPT
    {   // delete a pointer
    static_assert(0 < sizeof (_Ty),
        "can't delete an incomplete type");
    delete _Ptr; // Here is the breakpoint, it is trying to delete the Actor I inputed 
    }
};
```

I don't understand why it's giving me that error, I'm pretty sure I have a pretty solid including and forward declaration structure.

EDIT 1:

Okay so I did a test, I disabled the Tick function(it doesn't do anything right now), and I'm calling KillActor like so:

```
int main() {

    Planet b = Planet("B");

    Actor bactor = Actor();

    bactor.AddBehaviour<TestA>();

    b.KillActor(0); // This still results in the same incomplete type error!

    do
    {
        win.changed = false;
        win.GetCurrentPlanet()->Init();
        while (win.gameRunning)
        {
            win.Tick();
            //win.GetCurrentPlanet()->Tick(1);
            if (win.changed)
                break;
        }
    } while (win.changed);

    win.Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _Actor it gives me "Cannot Delete Incomplete Type" Error!_ Please **copy-paste** all of the error text, without paraphrasing it, and trying to shorten it.

Comment: You can't erase from a container that you are still iterating. Your killActor function is undefined behavior. Try erase remove like [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Okay I did so.

Comment: You have virtual functions but no virtual destructor- that's a code smell.

Comment: @Hello Since it triggered a breakpoint, which means, that it apparently is a runtime issue, as opposed to compile time one, did you use the debugger to investigate the call-stack, the values of related variables, etc.?

Comment: @manni66 Nope, I tried looping backwards to avoid that, and the same error persists!

Comment: You can't iterate if you are erasing!

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Okay it seems that it's calling the default Actor destructor.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius That means it doesn't recognize the definition of the Actor class(it sees it as an incomplete type), but I don't know why?

Comment: The “can't delete an incomplete type” part is a red herring. It’s in a static assert; if that fails, your program refuses to *compile*. You’re compiling just fine, but running into runtime errors. At runtime, there are no incomplete types.

Comment: @DanielH I understand, in the new example my program compiles without any errors, but at runtime gives an error, that's because I insert the actor to the allActors container of the planet at runtime, so at compile time the allActors container is empty, I think that is why it is happening at runtime?

Comment: @Hello My point was that this has nothing to do with incomplete types, because that only happens at compile time. The issue is probably that the pointer is being corrupted somehow, or the virtual destructor issue others mentioned, but it isn’t the order of your include files or anything else related to types being incomplete.

Comment: The issue probably has to do with the iterating while erasing, inheritance, or both. Please provide a [*Minimal* and *Complete* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @DanielH I understand, thanks for the information, also did you see my last edit? That makes me think its not something about iterating! I'll try virtual destructors and see what goes on!

Answer (score 0):

You can't erase from a container that you are still iterating. Your killActor function is undefined behavior. Try erase remove like [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)

You have virtual functions but no virtual destructor. Fix it.

Comment: That does not seem to be the problem, the problem is that the class Planet sees Actor as just class Actor; But I don't know why since I have included everything correctly and the implementation is going on the Planet.cpp!

Comment: You can erase if you do it on the last element. If not, the internal code (something like "erase at begin + pos") will try with a wrong iterator.

Comment: @manni66 I also tried disabling the Tick function and calling KillActor, before any looping, still the same!

Comment: @Ripi2 I updated with a new example, please check it out.